# Querying the User's table in Lightswitch 2012

Tags: visual-studio-lightswitch

I've a table with some categories and I need to assign to that categories the users that have access to the app. I know that the users are registered in the table "aspnet_Users" but I don't know how to create the relationship between the categories table and the "aspnet_Users" table because that table doesn't appear in the DataSource of my project. With such relationship I can show an auto complete box with the users so an administrator can assign the users to the categories in an editable grid.

I need this bind between the users and categories because knowing that relationship I can limit the access to the users to their category only.

Any idea about how to do that?

Comment: I think I found the solution here http://traf-o-data.blogspot.com/2011/08/linking-lightswitch-data-to-logged-in.html I'll try it later

Comment: Anyone can give me a link with a tutorial explaining how to create a Lightswitch 2012 WCF RIA Service project. I've tried the tutorial in the blog in the comment above and some other but they don't work probably because they're targeting LS 2011 and I'm workinh in LS 2012. When I try to add the "Reference to a WCF RIA Service" in the wizard the listbox with "Available WCF RIA Classes" is empty.

Comment: Solved, the problem was that by default VS2012 target the framework 4.5 and it has to be targeting the framework 4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer in this blog http://traf-o-data.blogspot.com/2011/08/linking-lightswitch-data-to-logged-in.html